# Replicating Image Flowchart in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a flow chart that was originally an image which ought to be simple enough to translate into CSS, but as I have little skill in CSS div manipulation I was hoping the wizards of Stack Overflow could help.

[image: A flowchart with three heights, where the object in the third column is the product of the previous two items]

I'm trying to replicate the above image in CSS. It doesn't have to look exactly the same, but I'd like to keep the basic layout the same.

I've taken a stab at the second and third columns just to see if I could get that part figured out, but I can't seem to get the second item in the second column to line up with the first item in the second column.

If someone could help me with just that portion, I would be eternally grateful.

```css
.RoleContainerTop {
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.RoleContainerMiddle {
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  float: left;
}
.RoleContainerBottom {
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.RoleContainer p {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="RoleContainerTop">
      <p>
        Abracadabra
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="RoleContainerMiddle">
      <p>
        Shazam
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="RoleContainerBottom">
      <p>
        Alakazam
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. The key is to create your columns of variable width, and from there it's pretty simple. I chose percentage width but you could do it however you like.

I would also advise you to consolidate your css a bit :). You're repeating alot of code that is shared between like elements.

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column-25 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.column-25:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.block.center {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-25">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-25">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-25">
    <div class="block center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-25">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From here, you could look into absolute positioned elements with some :before/:after wizardry to create the arrows if you'd like.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s8zjppaL/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: Sorry, quick question; there doesn't seem to be a style class for "container". When I try to embed this code in my control and place it in a page, it doesn't 'fill' the area. I suspect it's because I'm missing something in the container class. Could you help?

Comment: Figured it out--I added a height to the container div, and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it. You may not even need the container in your case, just have something to wrap the columns in.